# check visible text isn't show up in DOM while Cucumber scenarios run

Tags: ruby, web, automation, cucumber, watir

I'm using Cucumber and Watir in my web automation project (written in Ruby). 
I've a set of feature files with scenarios that I am constantly running. 
I've received a task to add an additional global check that makes sure that a set of strings does not show up on any of the DOM of any of the pages in any of the scenarios that I run.

For example, I've a scenario called 'Login to environment'. While running through that scenario and the normal flow for logging into the environment, I need something that also checks that some string `bla` doesn't show up in any of the HTML DOM. Also, I need this to happen for every other scenario that I have.

What is the correct way to implement such functionality in Cucumber/Watir/Ruby?

Comment: Why do you need to check that this text does not exist? I suspect this is not a cucumber problem, but might be a browser automation issue.

Comment: I think the solution depends on how you're setup now. For example, if you were using a Page-Object pattern, you could go check for those Strings every time you initialize a page object (though that wouldn't catch if the bad Strings occurred after an action). If you just wanted after each scenario, you could implement a Cucumber AfterHook. It might be overkill, but if you wanted to be safe, you could check after every single action by using Watir's hooks feature.

Comment: Watir's AfterHooks is what I searching for!    Thank you for help